# making urls clickable for wordpress custom post type field?

Tags: custom-post-types

Here is the code I'm using to add a custom field to a post type I have set up. As you can see it creates an input box which allows me to add whatever I want. I want to put urls in this box (without the "http://", e.g. "example.com") and have them be automatically clickable. Is there a way?

```
add_action("admin_init", "add_friends_fields");

function add_friends_fields(){
    add_meta_box("artist_links", "Links", "artist_links", "friends", "normal", "low");
}

function artist_links(){
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $artist_links = $custom["artist_links"][0];
    ?>
    <label>Links:</label><br /><br />
    <input size="50" name="artist_links" value="<?php echo $artist_links; ?>" />
    <?php
}
```

-edit-

```
    <section id="artists">
        <h2 class="title"><span>Artists</span></h2>
        <?php
            $i=1;

            $temp = $wp_query;
            $wp_query = null;
            $wp_query = new WP_Query();
            $wp_query->query('post_type=friends&posts_per_page=-1');

            while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();

            $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
            $artist_links = $custom["artist_links"][0];
            $artist_bio = $custom["artist_bio"][0];
        ?>

        <article class="mgm-artist<?php if($i%6 == 0) { echo ' right'; }; $i++; ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'video-thumb' ); } ?>
            <section class="artist-details">
                <p><span>Name:</span> <?php the_title(); ?></p>
                <p><span>Bio:</span> <?=$artist_bio?></p>
                <p><span>Link(s):</span> <?=$artist_links?></p>
            </section>
        </article>

        <?php
            endwhile; 
            $wp_query = null;
            $wp_query = $temp;
            wp_reset_query();
        ?>
    </section>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turning static urls into live links](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9938/turning-static-urls-into-live-links)

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry for posting twice. I tried to explain my needs better in this question since my last question wasn't clear judging by the answer I got. I can update the other one if needed.

Comment: @J82: Can you please present the code for where you are printing the custom field value to the page? That would be the more relevant part.

Comment: @wyrfel I may be wrong but isn't that in the code I posted? I checked my functions.php and the only other code is for registering the post type and saving the fields.

Comment: @wyrfel I think I misunderstood what you said. I've added the code that is in the page template.

Comment: **Note:** That first comment is automated, you'll see similar comments whenever a user with privs votes to close a question as duplicate(i didn't actually add the comment), just an FYI. I voted to close because i don't understand why you didn't just update the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this in your functions.php:

```
function my_format_artist_links($urls) {
    $urls = explode(',', $urls);
    $links = array();
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        if (empty($url)) continue;
        $links[] = '<a href="http://'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';
    }
    return implode(',', $links);
}
```

and then replace

```
<p><span>Link(s):</span> <?=$artist_links?></p>
```

with

```
<p><span>Link(s):</span> <?php echo my_format_artists_links($artist_links); ?></p>'
```

Comment: Thanks @wyrfel. There was an extra 's' added in the echo command so I changed that. One problem I'm having is getting the `http://` to prepend the urls since I'm typing them in like this `example.com, example2.com, etc.` I tried adding `http://` to the function like this: `<a href="http://'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>` however that only made the first url link in the correct format (i.e. `http://example.com`) while the rest of the urls linked to `%20example2.com` i.e. with `%20` in front of it. Also, there is the problem of a comma showing up after the last item which is not needed.

Comment: Your approach should work. Are you sure your links are properly comma-separated. This sounds like you are just getting them all stacked together by something else, not a ','. And if you get a comma after the last, it must be at the end of your custom post value. However, i'm making an edit, that get's rid of it.

Comment: Yes, my links weren't properly comma-separated. I was adding a space after the comma. So to make this work, I added a space after the comma on lines 2 and 8 of your code. I tried putting in the new line of code on line 5 `if (empty($url)) continue;` but the last comma is still there and won't go away. I'm not sure what you mean by `it must be at the end of your custom post value`.

Comment: implode() only inserts the comma between the elements of the array passed, not at the end. since there's no commas in my code elsewhere, i thought it could be at the end of your custom field value (at the end of your links). However, since the if-empty clause should care for that, it must be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Ah, spot on. There was an extra comma in the html. Thanks for your help!

Comment: One question here please. and please don't mind me being a nob . where to make this change exactly ? i means which file? `<p><span>Link(s):</span> <?=$artist_links?></p>` with `<p><span>Link(s):</span> <?php echo my_format_artists_links($artist_links); ?></p>'`

Answer (score 0):

just change `$artist_links = $custom["artist_links"][0];` in your loop to

```
$artist_links = '<a href="'.$custom['artist_links'][0].'">'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</a>;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I tried what you suggested and the links came up with the title of the post. Also, if I just enter "example.com" without the "http://", the links turn into "site.com/example.com". One last thing is if there are multiple urls separated by commas such as "example.com, example2.com, example3.com", is there a way to turn them all into their own clickable links instead of having them combined? Right now, if I put in multiple urls, it comes out like this: "sitename.com/example.comexample2.comexample3.com"